# jquery extend function if the objects are function

Tags: jquery

I came across a syntax as following. I can't quite understand what is it trying to do

```
        $.extend(
            {
                selectValue: function(value) {
                    // do some stuff
                }
            },
            this._selectorCallbacks
        )
```

Comment: Read the documentation for [jQuery's extend](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Answer (score 0):

> if the objects are function

Whether it's a function or not doesn't matter - it's just a property of the new object that's returned.

Essentially you have:

```
 var o = new { selectValue: function(value) { ... } };
 o._selectorCallbacks = this._selectorCallbacks;
```

And then you can call

```
o.selectValue("abc");
```